# Reset 3d model positions in A-Entity

Tags: three.js, aframe, webvr

I am using AFrame to load some 3d models from a third-party (using the GLTF-Loader). Unfortunately some of the models have their origins set to random x,y,z coordinates so they look offset when they appear. Is there any way to null their offsets without moving the a-entity they get loaded into?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can make a general assumption about what the center of a model is. Imperfect solutions are:

- Apply a manual offset from observation of the particular model.
- Edit the model center of coordinates in a 3D package like Blender or Maya and re-export to glTF.